# How to make comments visible in UI with anchor tag

Tags: html, pyqt5

I have below code for anchor tag, the display content of  tag is a comment and needs to be displayed. With below code only "383:" is coming in UI but I need complete content. I cannot modify the display content but any setting change or any other way can be considered.

```
<a href="file:///Build%20-%201410,%201424/Mass.jsp" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">383:    <!--Commented by me--ENDS--> </a>
```

Am using it in QLabel in PyQt5 but suggestions from any folks related to either PyQt5 or HTML can be provided.

Comment: Would JavaScript be allowed?

Comment: @mplungjan Sadly no!

Comment: Can you specify exactly what parts of the comment you want to keep, possibly with some examples of the provided input and expected output?

Comment: I need to display complete comment including <!-- and -->. So from the code provided above in the question the output should be: 383:    <!--Commented by me--ENDS-->

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to do it in JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("a").childNodes.forEach(c => console.log(c.nodeType,c.nodeValue))
```

```html
<a href="file:///Build%20-%201410,%201424/Mass.jsp" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">383:    <!--Commented by me--ENDS--> </a>
```

Comment: This code cannot be implemented, anyways thank you for the code, will refer this if required in future.